# How can I get last ActiveRecord query data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, so you forgive myself if the question is silly ...

I have a table and two forms, the first form is to filter (through checkboxes) and the second one is to search into the table.

What I would like is to search into the table with the filters already applied. I do not really know to do... how I can access from the controller search method to "already filtered" data.

Source code:

prices_controller.rb

```
def filter()
 @prices = Price.where(date: Date.today).order(price: :asc)
  if params[:filter1] != nil 
    @prices = @prices.where('filter1_field IN (?)', params[:filter1])
  end
  if params[:filter2] != nil 
    @prices = @prices.where('filter2_field IN (?)', params[:filter2])
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

def search()
  # Here I would like to use filtered prices, not all prices
  @prices = Price.where(date: Date.today).order(price: :asc)
  if params[:search] != nil
     @prices = @prices.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%")
  end
end
```

It works, but I am not using filtered values...
Are there any way to save the last query or something like that. I try to return to the search method the ActiveRecord::Relation but method where does not exists in this class. Other alternative is use the same form to filtering and searching.

I accept any kind of recommendation.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: both your pages have filter1/filter2?

Comment: In the same page, there are two forms and a table. The action of the first form is filter and the params are filter1 and filter2. The action of the second form is search and the param is search.

Comment: okay, so those two forms are two different actions

Comment: Correct, one action for each form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly because

1. The request that applies the filters and the request that triggers the search are 2 different requests.
2. Rails initializes a new controller instance for each request, so the controller for filtering and the controller for searching are 2 different objects. They don't share any instance variables.

You can however store the IDs returned by the filter phase in session, and use those IDs in search phase.

```
def filter
  @prices = Price.where(date: Date.today).order(price: :asc)
  if params[:filter1] != nil 
    @prices = @prices.where('filter1_field IN (?)', params[:filter1])
  end
  if params[:filter2] != nil 
    @prices = @prices.where('filter2_field IN (?)', params[:filter2])
  end      

  session[:price_ids] = @prices.pluck(:id)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

def search

  @prices = session[:price_ids].present? ? 
            Price.where(id: session[:price_ids]) :
            Price.all

  @prices = @price.where(date: Date.today).order(price: :asc)
  if params[:search] != nil
     @prices = @prices.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%")
  end
end
```

This approach has a drawback that you have to remove price IDs from sessions *at the proper time*, which can be hard do define.

Another approach is to ensure the browser sending the filter every time it requests a search (unless your Rails app is an API for single page application). This approach requires a redirect whenever filter is changed.

```
def filter
  redirect_to search_path(params.slice(:filter1, :filter2))
end

def search
  @prices = Price.where(date: Date.today).order(price: :asc)
  if params[:filter1] != nil 
    @prices = @prices.where('filter1_field IN (?)', params[:filter1])
  end
  if params[:filter2] != nil 
    @prices = @prices.where('filter2_field IN (?)', params[:filter2])
  end
  if params[:search] != nil
     @prices = @prices.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%")
  end
end
```

And your search form should contain 2 hidden fields for the filters

```
<%= form_tag '/prices/search', method: :get do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :filter1, params[:filter1] %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :filter2, params[:filter2] %>
  <!-- other form stuff ... -->
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a very bad bug here: your `IN` is broken.

ActiveRecord does SQL sanitization (to prevent SQL injection), so when you write:

```
query.where("a in ?", "hey")
```

You get `WHERE a in "hey"` on the SQL side.
It's the same in your query: your IN's parameter will get stringified.

If your `filter1` is `a,b,c`, the query will look like this:

```
WHERE a iN ("a,b,c")
```

Which is not what you want at all.

ActiveRecord is able to generate `IN` when you pass an array. So this:

```
query.where(a: [1, 2, 3])
```

will generate:

```
WHERE q IN (1, 2, 3)
```

which is what you want!

---

Now, with regards to the code itself...

The simplest way to do what you want is to move the code to another method, and reuse it in both places:

```
def filter()
 @prices = build_filter_query(Date.today, params[:filter1], params[:filter2])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

def search()
  @prices = build_filter_query(Date.today, params[:filter1], params[:filter2], params[:search]) #pass in an extra param here!
end

private
  def build_filter_query(date, filter1, filter2, search = nil)
    # use a local variable here
    prices = Price.where(date: Date.today).order(price: :asc)
    if filter1
      prices = prices.where(filter_field1: filter1)
    end
    if filter2
      prices = prices.where(filter2_field: filter2)
    end
    if search
       prices = prices.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    end
    return prices
  end
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I submit searching form, filter1 and filter2 params will be nil because they are in another form.

Comment: Ah! Note that you didn't post your HTML, so it was impossible for me to guess. A simpler option is using the same form and different button s.